# Prevent Outlook from adding line breaks

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, newlines

In my Outlook messages recently I have noticed that there are added line breaks after a certain number of characters. I suspect that these are being added to my outgoing messages only, not inbound messages, because inbound messages seem to have no added line breaks.

How can I determine if Outlook is adding line breaks to my outgoing message or if it is just the viewer showing the email as having line breaks in, but it does not actually have them?

Also, how can I disable the addition of line breaks either in the viewer or in the outgoing mail processor as the case may be?

Version is Microsoft Office 13

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

- create test email message with the following text (no line breaks)

1234567-10 234567-20 234567-30 234567-40 234567-50 234567-60 234567-70 34567-80 234567-90 23456-100 23456-110 23456-120 23456-130 23456-140 3456-150 23456-160 23456-170 23456-180 23456-190 23456-200

- send message to self
- message is received with the following line breaks (occurring every 70 characters):

1234567-10 234567-20 234567-30 234567-40 234567-50 234567-60 234567-70
234567-80 234567-90 23456-100 23456-110 23456-120 23456-130 23456-140
23456-150 23456-160 23456-170 23456-180 23456-190 23456-200

Note that I have Outlook set to use UTF-8 encodings. See below:

[image]

Also, I have tried modifying the setting "Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages." Whether the box is checked makes no difference.

Comment: This used once to work but I don't know if it still does : In the registry create under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Common\MailSettings` a DWORD called `WrapLines` and set it to 0. Which Outlook version are you on?

Comment: @McDonald's Yes, it breaking at 76 characters.

Comment: Are you in a domain environment with GPO settings or script changing registry settings or something potentially? Have you tried from the same machine with a newly defined Outlook profile to confirm if all Outlook profiles are affected by this regardless of the Microsoft settings being set per those quoted articles I posted? I'm talking Outlook profile and not Windows logon user account profile too by the way; easily define another Outlook profile and test from it and toggle to settings and test to confirm all are affected by this. What format is your Outlook text editor set to use now?

Comment: Did the above registry fix change anything?

Comment: 1) What type of e-mail account are you using [Exchange, POP, IMAP, etc.]? 2) Is this occurring for only plain-text messages, or does it also affect messages composed in HTML and/or Rich Text format? 3) Does the problem persist if you test from [another](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Outlook-e-mail-profiles-9073a8ac-c3d6-421d-b5b9-fcedff7642fc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bm5) Outlook profile?

Comment: If you need more information on how to update the registry, see [this article](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/to-control-line-length-in-internet-messages/) and especially the [Do It For Me](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/to-control-line-length-in-internet-messages/#doit) section that contains `.reg` files for Outlook versions 2003 to 2013 that you need to download and double-click to execute (for other versions of Outlook you will need to modify one of these files).

Comment: *Tyler, Tyler, he's our man, if* ***he cannot [edit] his answer with an update for clarification as all the comments have been requesting throughout different portions of this entire post***, *then no one can!!!*

Answer (score 2):

**Outlook 2013: How can I disable the addition of line breaks either in the viewer or in the outgoing mail processor as the case may be?**

> ### [How to prevent Outlook 2010 and 2013 from adding line breaks to sent plain text messages](http://blog.techhit.com/551102-how-to-prevent-outlook-2010-and-2013-from-adding-line-breaks-to-sent-plain-text-messages)
>
> When you send a plain text message, by default, Outlook will wrap text
>   and insert line breaks at 76 characters. This might break your
>   formatted paragraphs and URL links.
>
> There is a solution which requires registry changes, however there
>   also an option that fixes it without touching the registry. Here are
>   the steps:
>
> 1. Click on the **File** tab and select **Options**.
> 2. Click on “**Advanced**” in the left column of the *Options* window.
> 3. Scroll down to the “**International Options**” section.
> 4. Change “**Preferred encoding for outgoing messages**” to “**Unicode
>      (UTF-8)**”.
> 5. Click “**OK**” at the bottom of the *Options* window.
> 6. *Restart Outlook*
>
> **Note:** This only works for **Outlook 2013** and **2010**. For older
>   versions of Outlook (2007 and 2003), you have to use the registry
>   tweak
>
> <sub>[source](http://blog.techhit.com/551102-how-to-prevent-outlook-2010-and-2013-from-adding-line-breaks-to-sent-plain-text-messages)</sub>

Comment: I have seen this. This does not help me figure out at what point the line breaks are being inserted.

Comment: @TylerDurden - Do you have Outlook connected to Gmail, Exchange account, multiple accounts or what? I assume you are only seeing this on the items from the Sent Items and you do not see it when you are typying them up, correct? Is your default viewer set to Rich Text or HTLM and not plain text? I have an idea of what may be causing this such as your Word settings or the settings of the NormalEmail.dotm or whatever is pertinent which Outlook 2013 uses but explain your Outlook setup to me and confirm that it's only with sent items and not noticeable when you're typing each up?

Comment: @TylerDurden Can you also confirm that you are basically seeing extra line breaks or potentially send me a link to a screen shot of what you are seeing as well? I'm not sure if you're seeing single line breaks in the body being more than just one line break or if you literally see line breaks from sent items emails only after certain and specific characters typed in the affected message body?

Comment: I have that setting already made. I have updated my question to show steps to reproduce and a screenshot of my advanced settings.

Comment: I use Outlook 2010 in a corporate environment (Exchange, GPOs, etc).  This setting is available to me, but makes no difference.

Comment: @HaakonDahl Did you see my other answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1120068/prevent-outlook-from-adding-line-breaks/1235077#1235077 with some methods?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, yes, and while that is also good stuff, I have discovered that in my environment, it will never work.
There is a STIG setting which prevents the good thing from happening, so that the bad thing doesn't happen.
https://vaulted.io/library/disa-stigs-srgs/microsoft_outlook_2016_security_technical_implementation_guide?version=V1R1.3&compareto=V1R1
This is pushed by GPO, so userland has not hope.

Answer (score 2):

> ### [Line breaks are removed in posts made in plain text format in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287816/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text-format-in-outlook)
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> ---
>
> In Microsoft Outlook, you create a new plain text formatted post
>   containing line breaks. Outlook removes the line breaks and displays
>   the message. However, the posts do not display any indication that
>   this has occurred, other than the change in formatting. The
>   information bar message about extra line breaks does not appear,
>   either in the Preview pane or when you read the post. This processing
>   appears to happen when the message is initially posted.
>
> **Note** E-mail message items display the information bar as expected when the line breaks are removed.
>
> **Cause**
>
> ---
>
> By default, the Auto Remove Line Breaks feature in Outlook is enabled.
>   This causes the line breaks to be removed. Any two or more successive
>   line breaks are not removed.
>
> **Workaround**
>
> ---
>
> Use one of the following methods to work around this behavior.
>
> **Note** If you edit the existing post and you save the changes before you use one of the following methods, the line breaks are lost and can
>   only be replaced manually.
>
> ### Method 1. Disable the feature that removes extra line breaks
>
> This method disables the feature for all plain text items. To do this,
>   follow these steps:
>
> **For Outlook 2010 and later versions:**
>
> 1. Open Outlook.
> 2. On the **File** tab, click **Options**.
> 3. In the **Options** dialog, click **Mail**.
> 4. In the **Message format** section, clear the **Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages** check box.
> 5. Click **OK**.
>
> **For Outlook 2007 or earlier versions:**
>
> 1. Open Outlook.
> 2. On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**.
> 3. On the **Preferences** tab, click the **E-mail Options** button.
> 4. Click to clear the **Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages**
>      check box.
> 5. Click **OK** two times.
>
> ### Method 2. Use HTML or Rich Text format
>
> You can use HTML or Rich Text formats when you create new items. Or
>   you can change existing posts to these formats.
>
> *New posts*
>
> You can change the format for individual messages, or for all
>   messages. To change the format for all messages, follow these steps:
>
> **For Outlook 2010 and later versions:**
>
> 1. Open Outlook.
> 2. On the **File** tab, click **Options**.
> 3. In the **Options** dialog, click **Mail**.
> 4. In the **Compose messages** section, click either **HTML** or **Rich Text** in
>      the **Compose messages** in this format drop-down list.
> 5. Click **OK**.
>
> **For Outlook 2007 or earlier versions:**
>
> 1. Open Outlook.
> 2. On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**.
> 3. Click the **Mail Format** tab.
> 4. Click either **HTML** or **Rich Text** in the **Message Format** section.
> 5. Click **OK**.
>
> When you create a post item you can change the format for an
>   individual message. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> **For Outlook 2010 and later versions:**
>
> 1. Open Outlook.
> 2. On the **Home** tab, click **New Items**, and under **More Items** click **Post in
>      This Folder**.
> 3. On the **Format Text** tab, click **As HTML** or click **As Rich Text** in the
>      **Format** section.
>
> **For Outlook 2007 or earlier versions:**
>
> 1. Open Outlook.
> 2. On the **File** menu, click **New**, and then click **Post in This Folder**.
> 3. In Outlook 2007, click **HTML** or click **Rich Text** on the **Options** tab in the **Format** group. In Outlook 2003, or Outlook 2002, click **Plain
>      Text**, and then click **HTML** or **Rich Text**.
>
> Existing posts
>
> - In Outlook 2007, click **Other Actions** after you open the post item on the **Discussion** tab in the **Actions** group. Then, click **Revise
>     Contents** before you change the format.
> - In Outlook 2003, or Outlook 2002, open the post item, click **Edit**, and then click **Revise Contents** before you change the format.
>
> ### Method 3. Restore the line breaks in Outlook 2003 or Outlook 2002
>
> This method allows you to restore the line breaks that were removed.
>   To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open Outlook.
> 2. Open the post item.
> 3. Click **Format**.
> 4. Click to clear the **Unwrap Text** check mark.
>
> **Note** This option is not available in Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2007.
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287816/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text-format-in-outlook)</sub>

---

### Further Sources

> **Short Version Quick List**
>
> 1. Change the **`Automatically wrap text as text character`** to a longer character number than **70** to a more desired output (see below screen
>      shot)
> 2. Uncheck the box option **`Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages`** (see below screen shot)
> 3. Use **`Rich Text`** or **`HTML`** format instead of **`Plain Text`**
>
> In Outlook navigate: **`File`** | **`Options`** | **`Mail`**
>
> [image]

Comment: That was the first thing I tried 3 years trying to solve the problem. Whether that box is checked or not has no effect whatsoever on whether line breaks are added to an outgoing message. Are you testing these "solutions" or just copying and pasting from the internets?

Comment: @TylerDurden I've tested both with Outlook 2013 and it works as expected and ask explain in both posts. I would leave a comment with a link to the posts if I were guess. I think you need to tell more about how you have Outlook configured as I cannot emulate this behavior based on your test data/method so something must be missing as these solutions both work just fine from what I tested.

Comment: @TylerDurden It might be helpful to list all the things you've already tried as well/ This should be a simple solution to fix. Maybe rebuild the normal file as the comment from my answer long ago talked about. Without having full detail or knowing what all you have already tried, I'm not sure what you expecting but I'm sure there are many solutions to this problem per the inquiry wording. I'll happily delete both these answer later if you feel these are absolutely helpful to this problem (even for others). I'm glad to see you update the question after I answer stating those don't work tho.

Answer (score 1):

This used once to work but I don't know if it still does :

> In the registry create under
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Common‌​\MailSettings`
>   a DWORD called `WrapLines` and set it to 0.

If you need more information on how to do the above update to the registry,
see [this article](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/to-control-line-length-in-internet-messages/) and especially the
[Do It For Me](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/to-control-line-length-in-internet-messages/#doit) section that contains `.reg` files for Outlook versions 2003 to 2013 that you can download and double-click to execute. For other versions of Outlook you will need to modify the version number in
one of these files.

The file should look like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<office-version>.0\Common\MailSettings]
"WrapLines"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<office-version>.0\Common\MailSettings] "WrapLines"=dword:00000000` still works in Office 2016 or in my case Office 365 ProPlus. I manually added a new "DWORD (32-bit) Value" in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings` and renamed it to `WrapLines` - and done, since the default value is already `0x00000000` (0).
The value set in `PlainWrapLen` (76) is then safely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the way Outlook composes messages from "HTML" to "Plain Text."  This is accomplished by selecting FILE : OPTIONS : MAIL.  On the drop down menu, change HTML to Plain Text, then click OK.  This should correct the extra line spaces.  The spacing is not an issue when replying/forwarding to an email, only composing a new one.